# jQuery jPicker reset completely

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

If anyone experienced with jPicker, I would really like some help on this. I have a jPicker input box in a form, and when I post the form with Ajax, I try to reset the form back to it's original values. Except that I have no idea how to reset the jPicker box to it's original state, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jPicker** maintains the information for its control in the `$.jPicker.List[]` array. To remove the jPicker association with the control you will need to destroy its corresponding entry in the `$.jPicker.List[]` array.

Loop through the list of items in the array to find the one that references the control with

```
$.jPicker.List[index].id
```

When you find your control in the array, destroy it with

```
$.jPicker.List[index].destroy()
```

After destroying the array element, you will need to remove the SPAN jPicker html object associated with the control. If there is only one you can

```
$('span.jPicker').remove()
```

otherwise you will need to discover the specific html element

```
$(rowParent).find('span.jPicker').remove();
```

**Optionally**: if you are using class reference vs. id reference, use the .data() function to tag your control and use the following statement to retrieve the unique value

```
$( $.jPicker.List[index] ).data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unbind the jPicker from the element and then rebind it after you want to reset it, should make it back to default settings.

Comment: I tried that, but jPicker adds tons of elements and styles to everything, so I'm just trying to figure out how to do this without writing the code to do it. But seriously, jPicker doesn't have it's own way of doing this?

Comment: Not that I see from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

As explained above you could try something like this :

```
var id =$.jPicker.List[i].id; //getting the id of the element you've binded jpicker with
$.jPicker.List[i].destroy(); //destroying the instance in the jPicker List
$("#"+id).parent().find('span.jPicker').remove(); // destroying the span containing the graphical jPicker
$("#"+id).jPicker(); // And finally reinstancing the jPicker instance on your element
```

It should make blink your picker (removing then recreating).