# How to determine which element is bound when jPicker is expanded

Tags: jquery

When using [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) bound to multiple elements, how do I determine which element is bound to the instance of jPicker that is expanded? I'd like to customize the jPicker title based on that.

`$.jPicker.List` contains all the bound elements, but which one is associated with the expanded jPicker?

With the code below, I would ideally like to get the input id (one, two or three) when the jPicker is expanded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('.Multiple').jPicker();
    });
</script>

<input class="Multiple" type="text" id="one" value="e2ddcf" /><br />
<input class="Multiple" type="text" id="two" value="" /><br />
<input class="Multiple" type="text" id="three" value="fda0f7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hollister,

I answered another question concerning the jPicker and the information to answer your question is included in the solution.

[jQuery jPicker reset completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283965/jquery-jpicker-reset-completely)