# How can I close jPicker

Tags: jquery, color-picker, jpicker

I have some script in Ajax form, and I want to close jPicker when I click on form inputs(Ok or Cancel). I read the documentation and didn`t find anything. Any help?

This is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_best_id}').jPicker(
            {
                images:
                {
                    clientPath: 'js/jpicker/images/' // Path to image files
                }
            }
        );
        $(':submit').click(function(){
            $('#my_best_id').jPicker().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am late. But for visitors try this instead.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283965/jquery-jpicker-reset-completely/8284001#answer-10289362

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.jPicker').hide();
```

instead of:

```
$('#my_best_id').jPicker().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question without an accepted answer and I was wondering the same myself.

In my case I wanted just the jpicker dialog to be closed (as if clicking the cancel button).

So I couldn't use the following as suggested by @techfoobar

> $('.jPicker').hide()

because it would hide the color picker as well as the dialog.

To hide just the dialog -

```
$('.jPicker.Container').hide();
```

or you could invoke the cancel button's click event

```
$('.jPicker.Container').find('.Cancel').click();
```